# restrict or Revoke Firebase Database Secret _to Stop Read data from C# or Asp.net

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

hi every one  have aproblem with database secret
one day i have add my friend account as editor in my Firebase project 
he get and copy database secret key 
now he can login to my firebase database using c# application
i tried to make rule in my firebase rule

'''

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null"
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}
```

'''

but he still read data from his application 
i need to stop reading data except my android app 
please help me to make it more secure firebase realtime database

Comment: You can't limit by language. Just change your username and password

Comment: @Frank   i want to  revoke database secret key but  i think this will effect on users who use the android app

Comment: You need to push an update whit your app. Know in the future you should never share credentials. You should always create new one for everyone so you can control every access.